# How to undo a delete in TFS local workspace

Tags: undo

I have a project where TFS suddenly think a lot of files are deleted (local workspace).
I think it happened when I did a nuget `update-package -reinstall` to cure some unrelated problem.

The problem is I don't know which files contain changes since last check-in.

What is the best way to recover?
(I know I can backup the project, get latest and restore)

- If I try to undo the delete I get an error message saying the file already exist and must be deleted first.
- Promoting the files show an error message saying the files already has pending changes.
- `tfpt online` does not work on local workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Did NuGet put the deleted files in the recycle bin?

When you say "try to undo the delete I get an error message saying the file already exists and must be deleted" is there a writable file in there on disk? When tf.exe or VS undoes a delete, it's expecting there is not a writable file there already and will not overwrite it. If you rename the local file, you can undo the delete. This is probably why trying to promote the file also gives you an error message - there's a pending delete, and you can't add or modify a file that already has a pending deletion.

For each of the files with a pending delete, you'll need to decide if you want to keep the file that is on disk or not. You could also move them to a different location, undo the deletions, and then compare each file to decide which to keep.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Nuget didn't delete any files. They are still present in both the VS project and on disk. It is just TFS who has them marked as deleted. Move files, get latest and move back worked fine but I was just hoping there was an easier way.